# How to add accented characters to the "to" field of MimeMessageHelper?

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail, mime-message

I am sending emails with the Spring MimeMessageHelper, which uses the JavaMail API in the background. I would like to have an option to input the recipient's name like this:

```
private static void setTo(final EmailDTO emailDTO, MimeMessageHelper helper) throws MessagingException {
  if (StringUtils.isBlank(emailDTO.getToName())) {
    helper.setTo(emailDTO.getToEmail());
  } else {
    helper.setTo(emailDTO.getToName() + " <" + emailDTO.getToEmail() + ">");
  }
```

}

However, this throws a

```
javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal character in address ( Őry József <mail@testcompany.com> )
```

..when there are accented characters in the name.Which function shall I use for encoding the name in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("stalin@ussr.su", "Товарищ Сталин"));
```

Results in:

```
To: =?UTF-8?B?0KLQvtCy0LDRgNC40Ykg0KHRgtCw0LvQuNC9?= <stalin@ussr.su>
```

See [http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Message.html#addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType, javax.mail.Address)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Message.html#addRecipient%28javax.mail.Message.RecipientType,%20javax.mail.Address%29)

Comment: Спасибо! :-) For those using Spring, the MimeMessageHelper.setTo() method also accepts an InternetAddress instance.